# how to retrieve data from two tables in one query

Tags: mysql, vb.net

```
Try
  With com
    .Connection = con
    .CommandText = "SELECT * FROM attendance WHERE id_no='" & ComboBox1.SelectedValue & "'AND date BETWEEN '" & startDate.Text & "' AND '" & endDate.Text & "';"

  End With

  Catch ex As Exception
     MsgBox(ex.Message)
```

I'm trying to get the data from my payroll and attendance table

Comment: You need to look at paramatising this as you could be vunerable to sql injection. Also are your dates stored as dates in your db or as strings? If as dates you would need to convert the strings to dates e.g. AND A.date Between Convert(datetime, '" & startDate.Text & "', 103) AND Convert(datetime, '" & endDate.Text & "';"

Comment: @Mych thank you for the information sir, 
new learning's for me. this site is a big help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this

```
"SELECT A.*,P.* 
FROM Attendance A JOIN payroll P ON A.id_no = P.id_no
WHERE A. id_no='" & ComboBox1.SelectedValue & "'AND 
A.date BETWEEN '" & startDate.Text & "' AND '" & endDate.Text & "';"
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly if this isn't a simplified syntax for the purpose of the question please research SQL Injection as you really shouldn't write database queries with inline parameters that haven't already been sanitized.

You haven't provided enough information in your question, but you can certainly join tables together in a query,  you have different types of JOIN depending on your requirement. Please take a look at [this page in the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html).

Comment: THANK YOU sir....
already got it.... BIG HELP :D

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways to solve this. You can use a JOIN or a SUBQUERY
First a standard JOIN syntax:

```
SELECT *
FROM [table1]
JOIN [table2] ON [table1].[column] = [table2].[column]
```

And Subquery:

```
SELECT *
FROM [table1]
WHERE [table1].[column] IN (
    SELECT [table2].[column]
    FROM [table2]
}
```

Make sure that [column] values matches each other in both tables

These are just simple examples but you can search for more information about one of these techniques